# ReactNative iOS UNUserNotificationCenter: implement didReceiveNotificationResponse

Tags: ios, react-native, push-notification, onesignal

I'm building React Native application and use `scheduleLocalNotifications`. Inside the notification handler, I  navigate the user to the particular screen inside an app. It was working fine before OneSignal integration. After as I understand now I need to implement `UNUserNotificationCenter` delegate to handle notification clicks. I did that, but when I open the notification I receive the warning that says

```
App[134:16879] Warning: UNUserNotificationCenter delegate received call to -userNotificationCenter:didReceiveNotificationResponse:withCompletionHandler: but the completion handler was never called.
```

and the handler is not called.

Here's what I did.

I have my AppDelegate.h with the following code:

```
...
#import <UserNotifications/UserNotifications.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, RCTBridgeDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate>
...
```

Then, inside AppDelegate.m, I implemented the following method:

```
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response  withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(void))completionHandler   {
  NSLog( @"for handling push in background" );
}
```

and added this code to `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
...
UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
  center.delegate = self;
...
```

Can't understand what do I miss here.

Comment: You got notification in background ? Have Same issue .

Comment: I wonder if this is related to this issue: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/26199

Comment: Same here. Anyone got any solution ?